# Filling in Text of a VBulliten Private message

Tags: c#, browser, submit

Im trying to submit a private message in a webforum through C#. 
I can fill in every component except for the message box itself:

nk

The usual method of setting the innertext element of the textarea does nothing at all, it works for the rest of the page but not this?? I have no idea why and i can confirm the code is correctly identifying this area.
I can only imagine something else truly controls the display and submission value.
I have found :

When I set the value to anything but 0, the message will post but the text is missing each time.

Any ideas?

Comment: *I did finally figure this out. went another way with it as the below is blocked by vbulliten.
I still navigate to the logion of the site with a webbrowser, but then I get the cookies it generates and pass the details in a simply web request that copies the post of the form. Found the required info using SmartSniff. Very useful. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your favorite method to access a web page, but you can create a dummy WebBrowser form, then use a function like it:

```
    void SetText(string attribute, string attName, string value)
    {
        HtmlElementCollection tagsCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

        foreach (HtmlElement currentTag in tagsCollection)
        {

            if (currentTag.GetAttribute(attribute).Equals(attName))
                currentTag.SetAttribute("value", value);
        }
    }

    void CheckBox(string attribute, string attName, string value)
    {

        // Get a collection of all the tags with name "input";

        HtmlElementCollection tagsCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

        foreach (HtmlElement currentTag in tagsCollection)
        {
            if (currentTag.GetAttribute(attribute).Equals(attName))
                currentTag.SetAttribute("checked", value);
        }
    }


    void ClickButton(string attribute, string attName)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        HtmlElementCollection col = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");

        foreach (HtmlElement element in col)
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute(attribute).Equals(attName))
            {
                element.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
    }
```